# Virtual Oracle server for education?

Tags: oracle

I am currently a College Student and am taking an introduction to Oracle 10G. I cannot seem to make it to class all of the time and am curious to ask if there is any Virtual Oracle Server or something along those lines that would allow me to have a (in a nutshell) Virtual Database in which I can connect to via SQL* Plus and enter commands that I am learning? I am running Windows 7 Home Premium.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download and install the [Oracle Database XE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/overview/index.html). It's free and has a default database that will be useful for your tests. You could search for an [online SQL simulator](http://sqlfiddle.com/), but it's not as useful as your own machine.

Good luck with school and stop skipping classes. At least database classes, skip others :-).

Comment: My teacher didn't explain to well on how we would be able to work from home if the time ever came... Which is why I am asking. But thank you very much, I appreciate the help.

Comment: No worries, mate. From my part you could learn even from the pub. As long as you're curious and want to learn I don't even care why and I hope you'll find enough help here or on [StackOverflow](http://www.StackOverflow.com) (there you'll find more help with SQL problems) :). Try some simple video tutorials from youtube, like [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7bzgDlpgPKw) - for installation.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to do an installation directly on you PC, Oracle provide pre-built VM images which contain an 11g database, SQL Developer and other tools; more info [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html).

They are very quick and easy to set up - no DBA knowledge required; can run on any machine and O/S that runs VirtualBox; and best of all, if (or when) you really mess something up you can trash it and start again.

Incidentally, not sure why you are being introduced to 10g when it is already out of support. Don't think you'll notice much difference with 11g at this stage though, the basics don't change much.